# Orbeon 4.7 $.browser is undefined

Tags: orbeon

I have upgraded my application from orbeon 4.4 to orbeon 4.7. On loading forms, in the browser console I'm getting `$.browser is undefined`.

On debugging I found that orbeon 4.7 is using `jQuery v1.11.0` and `$.browser` is removed from `jQuery v1.9`.

Any idea why it is still using removed/deprecated `$.browser`??
How to solve this??

Answer (score 0):

Per the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.browser/), "This property was removed in jQuery 1.9 and is available only through the `jQuery.migrate` plugin. Please try to use feature detection instead.". So you could:

- Add the JavaScript for [jquery-migrate](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/) to your project.
- Change your code to check whether the feature you want to use is available, rather than rely on knowing in which browser it is available. (Most front-end developers would recommend you try to use this first.)